# Method Not Producing JTable

Tags: java, sqlite

I work for my local probate court, and one service we offer is email reminders. They fill out a form, it's entered in the system, and they will be notified when something is due. I've been allowed to create a program that will allow me to enter the information from the form to keep track of the attorney's who have signed up.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Attempt1 {

public static void setConnection() throws SQLException {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement state = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:dummy3.db");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    setStatement(conn, state);
    setInsert(conn, state);
    setQuery(conn, state);

}

// Test method
public static void setStatement(Connection conn, Statement state)
        throws SQLException {

    state = conn.createStatement();

    String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ATTORNEY "
            + "(ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,"
            + " NAME             TEXT    NOT NULL, "
            + " EMAIL     CHAR(50), " + " DATE             TEXT  NOT NULL)";
    state.executeUpdate(sql);

}

public static void setInsert(Connection conn, Statement state)
        throws SQLException {

    int entries;
    int i = 0;
    String input;
    String sql = "";

    state = conn.createStatement();

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("How many entries will you insert?");
    entries = keyboard.nextInt();
    keyboard.nextLine();

    while (i < entries) {

        System.out
                .println("Enter the values for ID, NAME, EMAIL, and DATE");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();

        sql = "INSERT INTO ATTORNEY (ID, NAME, EMAIL, DATE) " + "VALUES ("
                + input + ");";

        state.executeUpdate(sql);

        i++;
    }

}

// Test method
public static void setQuery(Connection conn, Statement state)
        throws SQLException {

    state = conn.createStatement();

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM ATTORNEY";



    ResultSet result = state.executeQuery(sql);

    /*
     * while (result.next()) {
     * 
     * String name = result.getString("NAME"); long age =
     * result.getLong("ID");
     * 
     * System.out.println(name); System.out.println(age); }
     */

    JTable table = new JTable(buildTableModel(result));

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(table));

     result.close();
     state.close();

}

public static DefaultTableModel buildTableModel(ResultSet rs)
        throws SQLException {

    ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();

    // names of columns
    Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
    int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
    for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {
        columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));
    }

    // data of the table
    Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
        for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
            vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
        }
        data.add(vector);
    }

    return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

    setConnection();

}
}
```

The issue I have is the method setQuery. It displays a table with the data entered. Where it currently sits at line 21, it does not display the table, nor does it seem to terminate the program. The goal was to update the table with a few entries, and then display the Jtable. When placed above the setInsert method, it displays just fine, and will reflect the new entries added the next time you start it. I'm still learning Java outside of a classroom environment on my own, so I can only imagine that this is riddled with poor coding, but I just can't seem to figure out why it doesn't display the table after the setInsert method is called, although I assume it's something painfully obvious. In it's current state, this program is just meant to test functions of SQLite with Java. From there it will be created with a GUI.

Small update:
While I'm still figuring out the debugger to solve my problem, I noticed if I do this:

```
setStatement(conn, state);
setQuery(conn, state);
setInsert(conn, state);
setQuery(conn, state);
```

Adding the setQuery method before the setInsert method and leaving the second setQuery in place, it will display the table both before and after the entry. it doesn't fix my problem, it's interesting to see that it did display the table and terminate the program properly after the setInsert method.

Second update:

I noticed something as I shut down my computer last night. As my programs were closing, I noticed a Jtable in the background. After fooling around today, I've realized that it actually is displaying the Jtable, but on the desktop. I have to minimize Eclipse to the desktop to see this. I've never seen this before, and I couldn't word it in a way that produced results on Google unfortunately.

Comment: In order to solve problems like this, you can use your IDE's debugger. https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/starting-the-debugger-session.html

Comment: @Synesso I've struggled understanding how to properly use my IDE's debugger. I'll do some more reading on it to utilize it to avoid questions that can be solved through debugging in the future.

Comment: No harm asking the question @DanceRandyDance. I wanted to let you know about the debugger though.

Comment: Now that I'm home I can give it a try. Someone provided an answer right before I left work with an explanation I believe, but it seems it was deleted.